# Where should I host/contribute a mapping from Stack Overflow tags to Wikipedia articles?

Tags: releasing-data, linked-data, wikidata, wikipedia, contributing-data

I had asked for a [mapping from Stack Overflow tags to Wikipedia articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270888/is-there-a-mapping-from-stack-overflow-tags-to-wikipedia-wikidata-entities) over at meta.stackoverflow, but no one seemed to find one, so I [started building my own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270893/4012405).

Where is the "right" place for me to host this information?  Right now, I have a [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SGojZbwgJTxKrihGbeNLO502Tj3zvmzIiPv_ECK8494) of manually entered data, but I'm concerned about data provenance since I'm about to add a few thousand links I've automatically pulled from the May 2014 Stack Overflow data dump and manually inspected.

I'd want it to be easy to access anagrammatically by others, easy for others to add links between Wikipedia/Wikidata and tags at all Stack Exchange sites, easy to source the assertion of any link, and easy to revert vandalism.  Ideally, if I could just dump it into some other system that handles this for me, I'd love it.

**Edit**: [This question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/where-to-upload-open-data) lists a few places for hosting data; which is most appropriate for this particular data set?

Comment: You could use Wikidata property instead of Wikipedia link, to make it more usable by other languages or other projects.. For example https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q859221 represents Java Swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best is to host your mapping directly on Wikidata. The property is https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1482

For instance, https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q859221 represents Java Swing, and has https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing as a Stack Exchange tag property:

[image]
[...]
[image]

License: public domain

Comment: Using Wikidata entities will be fine for the vast majority of links.  However, some link to subsections of Wikipedia articles, or to redirect pages that redirect to subsections of articles.  How should I handle these situations - should I make a new Wikidata entries?  Also, I don't think (but I certainly don't know; correct me if I'm wrong!) if links to external projects are really within scope of Wikidata - I don't think I could just have "has Stack Overflow tag page [tag]" as a property.

Comment: @sabas: That does not answer bskaggs's question. Could you please concert to a comment? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I can't do it. :/

Comment: Copy/paste into a new comment should be enough.

Comment: @bskaggs for the property I think you could try to ask to Wikidata contributors, I saw different properties for external websites (like Freebase)

Comment: @bskaggs I saw it has been created :) https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1482

Comment: @sabas Yup!  I'll do a status update in the answer.  Glad you noticed :D